# maven assembly plugin does not include my classes inside built jar

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, lambda

**Any code referenced below is from the project [here](https://github.com/dhorions/Course_HelloLambda)**

For the AWS Lambda, I have been trying to create a jar file based on the maven configuration defined here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>be.quodlibet</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloLambda</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>

  <plugins>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>assemble-all</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

When I try and build the fat JAR, upload it to AWS Lambda console, I see the error

The following package **[be.quodlibet.hellolambda](https://github.com/dhorions/Course_HelloLambda/tree/master/src/main/java/be/quodlibet/hellolambda)** was not added to the jar resulting in a

```
"errorMessage": "Class not found: be.quodlibet.hellolambda.helloHandler",
"errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
```

Comment: First having a maven-plugin as dependency is simply wrong. Furthermore have you checked if the package/classes are contained in the resulting jar file? Are you uploading the correct jar file?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am uploading the correct jar file. I have used an archive manager, I have checked that there is no directory called be to be found

Comment: Which file have you uploaded ?

Comment: @khmarbaise The `jar-with-dependencies` file which was the only jar generated as a result of the `maven assembly:single` task

Comment: You should call Maven via `mvn clean package` and that should result in creating the jar-with-dependencies file. And don't call the goal on command line...

Comment: @khmarbaise that worked correctly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @khmarbaise said in the comments, make sure you run "mvn clean package" and not "mvn clean assembly:single".